# Reaction of alkyl halides with potassium cyanide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Its given in my book that alkyl halides react with alcoholic potassium cyanide to give alkyl cyanide through $\mathrm{S_N2}$ mechanism.

But why do we need to use alcoholic $\ce{KCN}$ (potassium cyanide dissolved in alcohol)? My understanding is that polar protic solvent favours $\mathrm{S_N1}$ over $\mathrm{S_N2}.$

Comment: Solubility. Potassium cyanide does not dissolve in non-polar aprotics

Comment: Does alcohol have any role in reaction. Can we have reaction using only KCN

Comment: As @Waylander said, alcohol does not participate in the reaction itself. It only dissolves KCN so that it can dissociate to give the $\ce{CN-}$ nucleophile

Comment: Then instead of alcoholic can we use aqueous KCN

Comment: No because then the alkyl halide will not be soluble

Comment: Could use aq KCN in a two phase system (water/dichloromethane is good) with the addition of a phase-transfer catalyst such as tetrabutylammonium bromide which will transport the CN- into the organic phase.

Comment: @Waylander Correct, that is the common method